# How to set JTableHeader Look and Feel AND Color

Tags: java, swing, background-color, look-and-feel, jtableheader

this is my first post so any suggestions for how to make my post better would be awesome!

With the help of research from this website, I am able to generate a table that I can change the font of, change the alignment of, and maintain the current look and feel. I cannot however, change the color and am unsure what to do. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

After creating a JTable, I call:

table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(new HeaderRenderer(table));

```
private class HeaderRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer;

    public HeaderRenderer(JTable table) {
        setOpaque(true);//this is an attempt to change color
        renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)
            table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        renderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        Component cell = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

        setBackground(headerColor);//this is an attempt to change color
        //cell.setBackground(headerColor);//this is an attempt to change color
        cell.setFont(headerFont);//this successfully changes font
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in a direction or help me create a table header that is able to do be colorable, centered, and has a look and feel of "Nimbus"?

Answer (score 0):

All of the Nimbus properties are stored as keys in the UIManager's defaults table. You can retrieve and modify any of these values to customize the look and feel of your application. [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) page lists all of the Nimbus defaults